# Replicating ng-if with a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive, angular-directive-link

So I have this directive which will allow use declaratively hide or show elements:

```
<div cdt-visible-to="Admin,Moderator">...</div>
```

So our HTML becomes as declarative as possible. And this is what our directive looks like:

```
eDiscovery.directive('cdtVisibleTo', ['AuthService', function (AuthService) {

    return {

      restrict: 'AE',

      link: function ($scope, elem, attrs) {

        let cdtArray = String(attrs['cdtVisibleTo'] || '')
        .split(/[ ,]+/).map(i => String(i).trim()).filter(i => i);

        let ln = cdtArray.length;

        for (let i = 0; i < ln; i++) {
          let r = cdtArray[i];
          if(AuthService.hasPersona(r)){
            elem.removeAttr('hidden');
            return;
          }
        }

        elem.attr('hidden', 'hidden');

      }
    }
  }]);
```

So this is like a stand-in for `ng-show`.

My question is - what would a stand-in for `ng-if` look like?

What is the best way to remove elements from the DOM altogether with an Angular directive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the .remove() method of Angular element to remove an element from the DOM:
First get the angular element from your elem and then use the remove function

To do this perform:

```
angular.element(elem).remove();
```

I guess you want to remove it from the DOM if no one of the the Personas passed to the directive is authorized, so maybe you can use the following code:

```
var notAuthorized = false;
for (let i = 0; i < ln; i++) {
  let r = cdtArray[i];
  if(AuthService.hasPersona(r)){
    notAuthorized = true; //A Persona is authorized
    return;
  }
}

if (notAuthorized) {
    angular.element(elem).remove();
}
```

More info & methods of angular.element:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

Comment: thanks, is it necessary to wrap elem with angular.element()?

Comment: It's needed to use the remove() method. If you want to use native JS you can use elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);

Comment: thanks :) I think I will use angular.elem() then, I guess that just uses jQuery behind the scenes.